# grep command doesn't work when run remotely

Tags: bash, unix, rsh

I have a script like this:

```
if rsh $server grep "string" /usr/path/file.txt
then
   echo "yes"
else
   echo "no"
fi
```

Basically I want to check the file in remote server containing some specific strings. It doesn't work and always display "yes" whatever I put into "string".

However, if I remove "rsh $server", which means running locally, and put that file into local, it is working fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is? How can I modify my script?

Comment: are you sure you're testing the grep exit code, and not rsh's?

Comment: The exit status of `rsh` is just whether you were able to connect successfully, it doesn't transmit the exit status of the remote command.

Comment: Can you use `ssh` instead of `rsh`? It wil do what you want.

Comment: Found this wrapper for `rsh` that gets the remote exit status: https://gist.github.com/schlomo/7908037

Comment: @Barmar But it is working for rsh if I run the following command: rsh $server ps -fuctc | grep xxx | grep -v grep >/dev/null

Comment: That's because you're running `ps` remotely, but running `grep` locally.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot. I try: rsh $server cat /usr/path/file.txt | grep "string" and it seems like working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `grep` locally with data from the remote file:

```
if rsh $server cat /usr/path/file.txt | grep "string"
then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

This will be slow if the file is large, since the entire file has to be sent over the network so that the local `grep` can read it.

Comment: lol thank you very much. I just replied you and we are both find this solution at the same time I think :)

Comment: It was your `ps` example that gave me the idea for this.